# Use of uninitalized value in concatenation <.> or string at xyz.pl line 27

Tags: arrays, perl

I am writing this perl program and want to create an array which should be stored in output file according to the values of for loop. I am new to this programming.
This is my code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open( my $out_fh, ">", "output.txt" ) || die("Cannot open file.\n");
my ( $x, $y, $i, $j, $k, $p, $q );
my ( @Xrow, @b, @b_l, @w );

print("Enter the number of rows:\n");
$p = <STDIN>;
chop($p);

print("Enter the number of columns:\n");
$q = <STDIN>;
chop($q);

$x    = 2**$p;
$y    = 2**$q;
@Xrow = ( @b, @b_l, @w );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $x * $y; $i = $i + 1 ) {
    for ( $j = 0; $j < $x; $j = $j + 1 ) {
        for ( $k = 0; $k < $y; $k = $k + 1 ) {

            $Xrow[$i] = "$b[$j],$b_l[$j],$w[$k]";
            foreach (@Xrow) {
                print $out_fh "$_\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So output should look like for example p=q=1

```
Xrow0 b0 b_l0 w0
Xrow1 b1 b_l1 w0
Xrow2 b0 b_l0 w1
Xrow3 b1 b_l1 w1
```

so it should print like this in output file without any braces and "="

But I am getting error like this

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation<.> or string at xyz.pl in line 27
Use of uninitialized value within @b in concatenation<.> or string at xyz.pl in line 27
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't populate the arrays anywhere, so they stay empty.

But, in fact, you need no arrays to get the output you want.

Additional advice:

- Prefer [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp) to [chop](http://p3rl.org/chop).
- Declare the variables when you need them, not at the top of the program/subroutine.

How I'd do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $OUT, '>', 'output.txt' or die "Cannot open file.\n";

print "Enter the number of rows:\n";
my $p = <STDIN>;
chomp $p;

print "Enter the number of columns:\n";
my $q = <STDIN>;
chomp $q;

my $x = 2 ** $p;
my $y = 2 ** $q;

my $i = 0;
for (my $j = 0; $j < $x; $j = $j + 1) {
    for (my $k = 0; $k < $y; $k = $k + 1) {
        print {$OUT} "Xrow$i b$k b_l$k w$j\n";
        ++$i;
    }
}
```

Comment: @choroba..Thanks..I did it other way. I removed $i variable and change it to like $k$j because this was only name. But you actually give the output in the format which I wanted.